# Exporting some data from a table to another table using the export tool of ssms

Tags: sql-server, export, ssms

I want to copy about 35% percent -using the export tool from ssms- from a huge table to another table within the same server but with different database

The query used to restricted the source data can be breaked in my case into 16 small queries.

Is it possible to run 16 instances of export tool instead of runing one single query ? Is it going to be much faster If i run 16 instances of export tool ?

I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Th issue won't be the export but trying to get all 16 written back to your new table. 
You could overcome this using partitions by having a separate partition per query. Then switch out all partitions and you in effect have 16 tables to write to. Unless these are on separate disks you might not get any significant performance boost.

You are better off writing as a single export with multiple commits to a single empty Heap table and add your CI/ NCIs afterwards.

NB - Don't run SQL Export from your local PC - Run it on the Server instead or you'll be crossing the network.

Comment: SSIS allows you to set commit size. Set to 10 or 50 M.